# Adobe LiveCycle Flowed Form page margins

Tags: pdf, adobe, livecycle

I am using Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 8.2 to create a PDF for a survey.  I've managed to create the form from scratch using Flowed content boxes to allow the fields to dynamically expand so that I can print out the survey later.
The issue I am having right now though is that if a field is expanded and it pushes other fields below it beyond the page range, it will create a new page consisting of what couldn't fit on the previous page.  This is fine, but I would also like the form to automatically move the content below the last page up.  Basically, anytime a page is moved into a new page there is a lot of white space and id like the next page to be moved up under the newly positioned fields.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure the pagination of your Subforms using the **Object > Pagination** palette. You can also use the **Keep With Next/Previous** option to control the grouping of the objects on page break. Also make sure that your top level subform is set to **Flowed**.

Comment: Tacking on to what guillaumec91 said, I would look at where the parts of your form that are dropping to the next page are located. For example, if your page1 breaks over the margin, and page2 is set to "Place: Top of Next Page", then page2 would start on the next page instead of following page1 wherever it stops. Keep in mind that pages are treated like subforms in LiveCycle.